# Remove _sql_constraints

Tags: constraints, odoo

I want to remove `_sql_constraints`.

For example in `account_invoice.py` there is a constraints on number field. Now I want to remove it.

Can anyone have idea how to deal with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove your constraint using following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.constraint_table_usage
WHERE table_name = 'account_invoice';

ALTER TABLE account_invoice DROP CONSTRAINT account_invoice_number_uniq;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are talking about

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('number_uniq', 'unique(number, company_id, journal_id, type)', 'Invoice Number must be unique per Company!'),
]
```

If you remove from `.py` file then it will not remove from database. If you want to remove then you have to remove from database using `DROP CONSTRAINT`.

This will remove constraint from table and you can add duplicate entry.